# allow my laptop to ssh to my server through ufw from any ip

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, ufw

What are the different options for doing this? Allow any IP but require a certificate? Allow any ip but for added security require strong passwords? I suppose if there is an option for mac address identification, that would be a bad idea as mac addresses can easily be spoofed.

One last question: is there a way to only open to all IPs when my laptop is not connected to the LAN? Similar to a 2-factor fido key, or smartphone trusted device unlock.

Sorry, this question is kind-of all over the place. But I do hope this inspires new security features.

Thank you in advance and I did search the site for answers to these questions but either they have not been asked or I used the wrong key words.

Comment: Too many questions but basically allow ssh from anywhere and use ssh keys, disable passwords altogerher

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, I did kind-of go crazy with all the questions, but they were all related and I did not want to open a bunch of new question threads.